# Read txt file from local put into array and array into <select>

Tags: javascript, arrays, select, activex, text-files

Hi im making some application in htaEdit.
I need to take some txt file read each line of it and put each line in . 
Here's the code of select:

```
   <select  onchange="disablePodkategoriju();" style="width:220px;margin-left:80px;"  id="dropdown2" name="">
   <option value="" selected="default" disabled>Selektujte...</option>
   </select>
```

i have no idea how to make javascript for that. However i tested uploading file from local and managed in that  using ActiveX using this code:

```
      var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"); 
      var s = fso.OpenTextFile("test.txt", 1, true);
      var row = s.ReadLine();
      alert(row);
```

My txt file contain like 10 words 
AA
BB
CC
..
smt like that

Answer (score 0):

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"); 
var s = fso.OpenTextFile("test.txt", 1, true);
select = document.getElementById('dropdown2');
var arr=new Array();
var i=0;
do {
arr[i]=s.readLine();
}
while(s.readLine!=null);
for (i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = "option"+(i+1);
    opt.innerHTML = arr[i];
    select.appendChild(opt);
}
```

Comment: Thxs for asnwering but how should i implement ur code with mine above where i call for txt file?

Comment: I have edited the answer. This is something similar to what your code should look like.

Comment: Yea but i think its still not gonna work since theres no new line separator anyway thxs for help